# Oracle_ ROW_NUMBER for paging hierarchy query

Tags: sql, oracle, hierarchy, row-number

This time I face a problem that is paging query for a hierarchy table.

> table_name(id varchar2(50), id_parent varchar2(50) );

So for sample data I have:

```
WITH table_name AS
(
    SELECT '3' id, '' id_parent FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT '5' id, '3' id_parent FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT 's' id, '3' id_parent FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT '4' id, 'as' id_parent FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT 'aa' id, 'as' id_parent FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT 'as' id, '3' id_parent FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT 'ad' id, '3' id_parent FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT '2' id, '' id_parent FROM DUAL 
)
SELECT LPAD('-', 2 * (level - 1), '-') || id AS id1,
    id_parent, 
    rownum  --Seem not legit here
FROM table_name
START WITH id_parent IS NULL
CONNECT BY PRIOR id = id_parent 
--ORDER SIBLINGS BY id
;
```

This is expected output:

```
id          id_parent   rownum
2                       1
3                       2
--5         3           3
--ad        3           4
--as        3           5
----4       as          6
----aa      as          7
--s         3           8
```

For now I count on **rownum** for row_number to make paging. As Oracle hierarchy query's doc, this make sure I can display the tree as pre-order Traveral that's what we want, but as SQL in general, IMO it don't guarantee that the same-level-nodes will be sorted (or not?).

So I need something like `ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER SIBLINGS BY id)`. But I have got no luck searching for something like that.

Is there some way to work with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Order first and then generate the `ROWNUM` afterwards using a sub-query:

```
SELECT t.*,
       ROWNUM
FROM   (
  SELECT LPAD('-', 2 * (level - 1), '-') || id AS id1,
      id_parent
  FROM table_name
  START WITH id_parent IS NULL
  CONNECT BY PRIOR id = id_parent 
  ORDER SIBLINGS BY id
) t;
```

You need the outer query as the order in which execution happens in a query is:

- The rows are selected;
- Then the `WHERE` clause filters are applied (and the `ROWNUM` pseudo-column is
  generated for each row that matches all the `WHERE` clause filters - in this case there is no `WHERE` clause so all rows will be numbered);
- Then the `ORDER BY` clause is applied.

Applying this in a single query will get the rows found in the database then give them a row number and finally order those rows (not what you want). Using an inner query you can force the `ORDER BY` clause to be applied first and then the generation of the row numbers will occur, subsequently, in the execution of the outer query.

Comment: arr, thank you MTO, that's my lack knowledge in `rownum`. After reading your answer I have searched and found this helpful link too [On Top-n and Pagination Queries](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/issue-archive/2007/07-jan/o17asktom-093877.html) (although I had read it once before somewhere at asktom "__",